# Vue Lazy load refactor

Tags: vue.js, webpack, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load a lot of components in my app, I want to show a loading spinner while any of them is loading, and the same for error; so there is a lot of duplication.

```
   export default c => ({
     component: import(`${c}`),
     loading: loadingComponent,

     timeout: 3000
   })
```

I am trying to refactor this into a single function and using it like that

```
import lazyload from './lazyload';
Collection:   lazyload("./Collection.vue")
```

But webpack is not extracting the component as it normally does, I know that I am missing something.

Comment: Like this : https://pakainfo.com/load-more-data-from-database-using-vue-js-ajax-php/

Answer (score 0):

You need to be creating an async component *factory* (meaning *function*). Also the import module cannot be fully dynamic, there needs to be some prefix to the module path otherwise it could match literally any module and webpack needs to know which subset of modules it could possibly match at runtime to include them in the build.

> Fully dynamic statements, such as `import(foo)`, **will fail** because webpack requires at least some file location information. This is because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project. The `import()` must contain at least some information about where the module is located, so bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files.

I've made some adjustments to your code (untested):

**lazyload.js**

```es6
export default c => () => ({
  component: import(`./components/${c}`),
  loading: loadingComponent,
  timeout: 3000
})
```

**Example usage**

```es6
import lazyload from './lazyload'

export default {
  components: {
    Collection: lazyload('collection.vue')
  }
}
```

---

A better implementation, in my opinion, would be to avoid creating the dynamic import. I prefer webpack to know for certain which modules are definitely needed at build time instead of bundling together a subset of modules inside a directory.

**lazyload.js**

```es6
export default componentFn => () => ({
  component: componentFn(),
  loading: loadingComponent,
  timeout: 3000
})
```

**Example usage**

```es6
import lazyload from './lazyload'

export default {
  components: {
    Collection: lazyload(() => import('./collection.vue'))
  }
}
```

Now `lazyload` has no dependency on any specific component directory and can be used with any component.

Comment: https://pakainfo.com/load-more-data-from-database-using-vue-js-ajax-php/